# True statement with a false contrapositive?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic

Statement: $\forall m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $m$ is even and $n$ is even $\implies m\cdot n$ is even (true)

Contrapositive: $\forall m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $m\cdot n$ is odd $\implies m$ is odd or $n$ is odd  (false)

???

it should be true where $m\cdot n$ is odd $\implies m$ is odd **and** $n$ is odd, but that's not the contrapositive.

I'm confused

can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please give a little more details on what your question is exactly? What does the true or false mean in this context? What was your answer? What are you confused about?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the "or" here as exclusive or (“one or the other, but not both”, “exactly one of them”). But what is meant with ”or” in the context of mathematics is the inclusive or (“one or the other or both”, “at least one of them”). So in your case, at least one of $m$ and $n$ is odd.

Comment: One way to think of it is that if a statement considers only *some* cases lead to *some* conclusions. THe contrapositve claims that all other conclusions, rule out specifically the *some* cases and ignores all others.  In this case *only* the case $m,n$ both even is considered.  So the contrapositive only rules out the *one* case; all others aren't ruled out because they weren't considered in the first place. A contrapositive only rules out what the positive consider; not what it didn't consider.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have written the correct contrapositive, and it is true. If $m \times n$ is odd, then $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd.

You are also correct in noticing that in fact, if $m \times n$ is odd, then $m$ and $n$ are **both** odd. This is a stronger statement, since notice that
$$ \mbox{$m$ and $n$ are both odd } \implies \mbox{ $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd}$$

This stronger statement is the contrapositive of
$$ \mbox{$m$ is even or $n$ is even } \implies \mbox{ $m \times n$ is even}$$

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is true, but overly strong.  We don't need *both* $m,n$ even to get an even product.

As a result, the contrapositive is true, but overly weak.  If $mn$ is odd, then is is true that one, or the other, or both are odd.  In actuality we know that both must be odd but the weaker statement $m$ or $n$ is odd is certainly true.

A weak statement isn't false (unless the statement is claiming an if **and only** if claim); it's just weak.

.....

If I had a lot of data and statements and I did a bunch of logical and correct manipulations, an arrived to the conclusion:  New York City has a population of at least 17 people---  that's not a false conclusion;  it's an utterly ridiculous and comically weak conclusion.  But it *is* true.  The population of New York City *is* at least 17 people.

This is similar.  If $mn$ is odd the $m$ or $n$ is odd.  Yes, in fact they are *both* odd.

======

Consider the four cases:

$m$ odd; $n$ odd.  $mn$ odd.  The output is counter to the positive so this will be considered by the contrapositive.

$m$ odd; $n$ even. $mn$ even.  This case was ignored by the positive but doesn't counter the output.  As it was ignored by the positive, it will not be ruled out by the contrapositive.

$m$ even; $n$ odd. $mn$ even.  Same as above.  This was ignored by the positive and so will not be ruled out by the contrapositive.

$m$ even; $n$ even. $mn$ even.  This is the only case considered by the positive that gives a definite result.  Therefore this is the only case that will be ruled out by the contrapositive when we consider the other result.

Positive:  If $m$ and $n$ are *both* even; then $mn$ is even.

Literal but lazy Contrapositive:  If $mn$ is not even; then $m$ and $n$ are not both $even$.

Using more natural language and the knowledge that "not even = odd" and "not both A and B = (not A) or (not B)" we have

Contrapositive: If $mn$ is odd; then $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd.

.....

Our impression is that the contrapositive is too weak, but that's because the positive was too strong.

We we *really* want is:

Positive: $m$ or $n$ is even; then $mn$ is even.

Contrapositive: If $mn$ is not even; then it is not true that at least one $m$ or $n$ is even.

Or: If $mn$ is odd; then $m$ and $n$ are odd.

That's a positive that was broad enough to be necessarily complete, which results in a contrapositive that is strong enough to cover every thing.

BUT... that *wasn't* the positive we were given, overly strong positives result in weak contrapositives and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive is true. If m×n is odd, at least one of m, n is odd, since both are odd.

Answer (score 0):

**Conditional Statement**: If both the two numbers are even then their product is even.

**Contrapositive statement**: If the product of two numbers is not even then both numbers can't be even.

Observe that your observation doesn't contradict anything.